# Flutter: Tabbar vs BottomNavigationBar

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to figure out the best way for bottom navigation with swipe enabled. I found two promising widgets: Tabbar (with TabBarView) and BottomNavigationBar. The tabbar is easy to use and has a controller property which allows swiping between tabs easily. But there is no way to set the backgroundcolor (or am I wrong?). The bottomnavigationbar allows customizability outside of the appBar but doesn't work with controllers. So how would I work with the bottomnavigationbar? Should I manually show and hide the page/widget?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting the background color on a TabBar can be done by wrapping it in a Material of the color you want. It's unusual to have one of these at the bottom of the screen though.

You could use the BottomNavigationBar's onTap to trigger page changes in a PageView if you want the views to be swipeable.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about the color thing yet! Any reason why using a TabBar at the bottom isn't usually done? It looks like an easy way to implement bottom tab navigation!

Comment: It doesn't appear in the material design spec, possibly because the tab selection indicator would make more sense on top instead of the bottom of the tab bar. But if you like the way it looks, it's your app, go for it! :)

Comment: @CollinJackson Thanks for your numerous inputs on helping us with flutter! Following your recommendations I can place the TabBar at bottom and style it as I choose, separately I can use the BottomNavigationBar onTab to trigger page changes. What I still cannot do is to highlight the correct BottomNavigationBarItem when I swipe the body to a new tab. I have `currentIndex: _tabController.index` in the BottomNavigationBar, but still the tab highlight does not change when swiping. Do I need to set state on this somehow? Thanks.

Comment: Managed to connect TabController to BottomNavigationBar using addListener on the TabController with a callback. I think this is proper. Cheers!